# Assign jquery var to model attribue

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

How can I assign a jquery value to a model attribute in rails?  Something like this?

```
<script>
    var jvar = 10;
    <%= :data %> = jvar
</script>
```

But that doesn't seem to work

Comment: This requires ajax as javascript is only on the client side and your rails is on the client side

Comment: Could you elaborate on the bigger picture, and why/what you're trying to do? You can create a very simple javascript function for persisting ruby model attributes via ajax.

Comment: I'm counting row numbers in a table using a javascript function.  I display these rows inline with the table as a column.  However, when I save my model's attributes, those values disappear.  I would like them to not do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little bit backward in its conception. Once you're in Javascript and HTML land, the only way to get the variable assigned back to the Ruby model object is by submitting a form or using Ajax. You need to get that Javascript data out of Javascript land and back into Ruby land on the server side.